# My Email-To-Case Email Service Address is not accepting all mail

Tags: apex, email, servicecloud, email2case

My company is using Email-To-Case.

Our main support@acme.com is accepting the email and attempting to forward it to the Salesforce Email Service Address.

Salesforce is not accepting the forwarded email.

Is Salesforce rejecting it as spam due to SPF failure?  The forwarded email is coming from Mimecast (205.139.110.61) which is not a valid server in the SPF record for linde.com.

```
Received-SPF: Fail (protection.outlook.com domain of afrox.linde.com does not
 designate 205.139.110.61 as permitted sender)
 receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=205.139.110.61;
 helo=us-smtp-1.mimecast.com;
```

We need to have Salesforce accept any forwarded email from Mimecast. How can we make this happen?

Below are our deliverability settings.

[image]

Comment: Do you have 'Advanced Email Security Settings' checked in 'Email to Salesforce' settings for your org?

Comment: @akarnid  No - We do not have advanced email security settings